# Using induction, prove that $(-7)^n -9^n$ is divisible by $16$

Tags: induction, proof-verification

First of all, I think the problem should be $(-7)^n -9^n$ is divisible by $-16$ because if I test the basis by letting $n=1$, I have $-16$ instead of $16$.

Edit: Alright ... I sort of understand why it really is divisible by $16$. Even though I had $-16$ as the answer for the basis, if I divide $-16$ by $16$ then I get $-1$ , so the book didn't make an error, but the fact that I was dealing with a negative number for the basis made me freak out a little bit.

$(-7)^1 -9^1 = -7-9 = - 16$

Now for the induction...this is my attempt.

$P(k) = (-7)^k -9^k $

For $P(k+1)$

$(-7)^{k+1} - 9^{k+1}$

$(-7)^k * (-7)^1 + [9^k  * (-9)^1]$

$(-7)^k -9^k = -16m$

$(-7)^k  = -16m +9^k$

$(-16m +9^k )* (-7) + [9^k  * (-9)]$

$(-16m * -7) +(9^k * -7) + (9^k  * -9)$

$(-16m * -7) +(9^k) * (-7-9)$

$(-16m * -7) +(9^k) * (-16)$

Comment: Btw, the start is "even more clear" if on starts with $n=0$ instead of $n=1$

Comment: if I start with $N=0$ that would mean that $(-7)^0-9^0$ and it's $1-1 = 0$

Comment: Note that $-16=-1\times 16$ is divisible by $16$. It is not quite clear what your question is.

Comment: You finished the entire proof. finally, it is coming:  $(-16)*[(-7m)+(9^k)]$. So what is the problem?

Comment: I just wanted to see if it's correct... should've put the proof-verification tag

Comment: @MarkBennet $-16$ is divisible by $16$? So I guess the book didn't make a mistake, but still it freaked me out a bit because when I did the basis and let $n=1$ I got $-7-9 = -16$

Comment: Note that all the terms for positive $n$ are negative.

Comment: umm yes I do see that it's negative...

Answer (score 1):

At $n=0$, we have $16\mid(-7)^0-9^0$.

Then, suppose that $16\mid(-7)^n-9^n$,
$$
\begin{align}
(-7)^{n+1}-9^{n+1}
&=(-7)(-7)^n-9\cdot9^n\\
&=-\color{#C00000}{16}(-7)^n+9(\color{#C00000}{(-7)^n-9^n})
\end{align}
$$

Comment: But a base case of 1 is clearer.

Comment: @TomCollinge: I really don't find a base case of $1$ any clearer, and a base case of $0$ extends your result to one more integer.

Answer (score 0):

If $P(k)=(-7)^k-9^k$

$P(k+1)-9P(k)=(-7)^{k+1}-9^{k+1}-9[(-7)^k-9^k]=(-7)^k(-7-9)=-16(-7)^k$

Or $P(k+1)-(-7)P(k)=(-7)^{k+1}-9^{k+1}-(-7)[(-7)^k-9^k]=-9^k(9+7)=-16\cdot9^k$

So in either way, $P(k+1)$ will be divisible by $16,$ if $P(k)$

Now establish the base case i.e., $k=1$