# Prove by induction: If $h$ and $k$ are any two distinct integers, then $h^n-k^n$ is divisible by $h-k$.

Tags: induction

If $h$ and $k$ are any two distinct integers, then $h^n-k^n$ is divisible by $h-k$.

Let's start with the basis. Let $n=1$, then 
$h^1-k^1 = h-k$

Now for the induction, I can't use $k$ because I don't want to be confused. So let $P(r)$ for $h^n-k^n$ and that's  $h^r-k^r$

$h^r-k^r = h-k$

$h^r = h-k +k^r$

So, for $P(r+1)$

$h^{r+1}-k^{r+1}$

$h^r * h^1 - k^r * k^1$

$ (h-k +k^r) * h -k^r *k $

This is the point where I'm not certain if I should distribute the $h $ all over the place...so here it is

$ (h*h-k*h +k^r*h)  -k^r *k $

$ (h*h)+(-k*h) +(k^r*h)  -k^r *k $

$  (h)*(h-k) +  (k^r)*(h-k)$

$(h-k) * (h+k^r)$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-an-bn-is-divisible-by-a-b

Comment: I don't see how you get the first line: $h^r-k^r = h-k$

Comment: Isn't the first line just for $P(r)$? So, $h^r-k^r$ ?! since we're testing $P(r)$ in the induction ?

Comment: oh! I think after I got my $h^r$ for $ h^r * h^1 - k^r * k^1$, I had to replace it. So that's where $h^r-k^r = h-k$ comes in... I just added $k^r$ to both sides

Comment: I did this the same way as the previous two problems that I asked a few hours ago. It seems that method was the easiest route for me.

Answer (score 5):

For $n=0$: $h-k\mid h^0-k^0$.

Suppose $h-k\mid h^n-k^n$, then
$$
\begin{align}
h^{n+1}-k^{n+1}
&=h\cdot h^n-k\cdot k^n\\
&=(\color{#C00000}{h-k})h^n+k(\color{#C00000}{h^n-k^n})
\end{align}
$$
Since $h-k$ and $h^n-k^n$ are divisible by $h-k$, so is $h^{n+1}-k^{n+1}$.

Comment: wait a sec...how come that proof is super short ?

Comment: This answer is essentially the same as answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668202/using-induction-prove-that-107n-97n-is-divisible-by-10) and [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668272/using-induction-prove-that-7n-9n-is-divisible-by-16).

Comment: yeah, but it seems that I have more confidence in those two previous questions than in this one. I just assumed that I needed to distribute an $h$ and then factor ...

Answer (score 2):

Notice that you have
$$
\begin{align}
 &a^2-b^2 = (a-b)(a+b) \\
 &a^3-b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2) \\
 &a^4-b^4 = (a-b)(a^3+a^2b+ab^2+b^3) \\
etc
\end{align}
$$
In fact for every integer $n \ge 1$ you have
$$
 a^n-b^n = (a-b) \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^kb^{n-1-k}
$$
Of course you can prove this formula by induction, or just develop the expression and order the terms of the sum to check the equality.

With this formula you see immediately the divisibility.

Comment: I need to do it through induction, not algebraic factoring. I just need to know if my attempt was right or did I mess up somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to write $$h^{r+1}-k^{r+1}=hh^{r}-kk^{r}=(h+k)(h^r-k^r)-kh(h^{r-1}-k^{r-1})$$

in a similar fashion to what we do to prove that if $\alpha,\beta$ are the roots of $f[X]\in\Bbb Z[X]$, $\alpha^n+\beta^n\in\Bbb Z$ for every $n\in\Bbb Z$. Indeed, $\alpha+\beta,\alpha\beta\in\Bbb Z$ by Vieta and

$$\alpha^{n+1}+\beta^{n+1}=(\alpha+\beta)(\alpha^n+\beta^n)-\alpha\beta(\alpha^{n-1}+\beta^{n-1})$$